# How can I manage environments to wrap functions and avoid environment issues?

Tags: r, expression, eval, environment

Here are 4 functions which mimics a family of functions from basic to advanced.

```
f1 <- function(expr,envir) {
  eval(expr,envir)
}

f2 <- function(expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  f1(expr,parent.frame())
}

f3 <- function(x) {
  lapply(1:3, function(i) {
    f2(x+i)
  })
}

f4 <- function(...) {
  f3(...)
}
```

`f1` is the fundamental one, `f2` calls `f1` with an expression, `f3` iteratively calls `f2` with `x` defined in its body frame.

Calling `f3` yields

```
> f3(1)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

which has no problem because the `x` is evaluated correctly in `parent.frame()` of `f2`. However, if a wrapper function `f4` is called, an error occurs:

```
> f4()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I inspect the parent environments local to `f2` in line and find that `parent.frame(3)` contains `x: missing`.

Is there a way or good practice to manage the environments so that I can wrap functions like `f4` without worrying too much about the parent environment issues?

Comment: I'm not sure this has to do with environments. If you just call `f3()` with no parameters you get the same error. And all `f4()` does is call `f3()` with no parameters. When you do `f2(x+1)` you are forcing the evaluation of `x` in that context, thus is it `f3()` that looks for the value of `x` in the parent frame, and `f2()` is being passed a simple numeric value.